# Record square video on React-Native

Tags: react-native, video-processing, react-native-ios, react-native-camera

I'm trying to build an react native app that allow user to record and publish square video (like instagram). Here are my attempts :

1 - Find a library that crop video in app => fail

2 - Find a library that show a square camera screen => fail

3 - Record video using native picker and use hidden overflow to display square video => success

I think that solution 3 is not optimal, do you have others ideas ?

(Library I checked : react-native-image-picker, react-native-image-crop-picker, react-native-camera, react-native-video-processing)

Answer (score 0):

I think `react-native-camera` and `react-native-video-processing` is the right combo. You capture video with camera and then aggregate it with processing lib. To display a preview square screen to a user it would be best to crop camera view and make it look as a square. Later, in background, make it actual square.

I'm messing with this currently too :)